# Groovy Script Providing Null for Output in Basic Scipt

Tags: groovy

I have a basic groovy class and script that class the script that should output some basic information. However what the class takes in is not outputted. Rather, the output is simply null and I am not sure why. See screen shot below.

[image: Screen Shot of output]

The class code is:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class Tweet {

    String UserName
    String First
    String Last
    String Tweet
    Integer retweet
    Date createdOn

    public Tweet(String UserName, String First, String Last, String Tweet) {
        UserName = UserName
        First = First
        Last = Last
        Tweet = Tweet
        retweet = 0
        createdOn = new Date()
    }

         void addToRetweets() {
             retweet +=1
         }

}
```

The script used to create the output is:

```
def tweet = new Tweet("cmith", "Chris", "Smith", "Today is going to be a good day")

println tweet
```

Any help with this would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having trouble because the constructor parameters are the same names as the instance variables which Groovy can't distinguish which is which so you are basically executing against the parameters and doing a bunch of no-ops (ie x = x doesn't change the value of x).  Use the `this` reference to denote the instance variables as the assignments and it'll allow Groovy to understand which variable is which.

```
    public Tweet(String UserName, String First, String Last, String Tweet) {
        this.UserName = UserName
        this.First = First
        this.Last = Last
        this.Tweet = Tweet
        retweet = 0
        createdOn = new Date()
    }
```

Comment: Tank you. I missed seeing that and now remember learning that. :)